# How to save a list to a text file in python?

Tags: python, list, numpy, text, save

I have a list in python where each element in the list contains an array, this takes about 20 minutes to run each time so I was wondering if there was a way I could save it to something like a text file so I can call it back in the same format. Thanks

Comment: Use pickle from the standard library. Otherwise, your problem has no context.

Comment: Give us some more details of what your problem really is, some sample code would be great.

Comment: I haven't heard of pickle before, how can it be used?

Comment: here's a great walk through
https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle

Comment: what exactly takes 20 minutes to run? preparing a `list`? then only it would make sense to pickle it (if it is not going to change further)

Comment: Pickling is a rather inefficient way to store numpy arrays. How large are they? Do they have all the same dimensions?